# How do I access own parameters in class based views - Django

Tags: django, django-views, django-urls, django-generic-views

I have this url:

```
url(r'^ceniky-edit/kadernictvi/$', views.CenikView.as_view(typ='kadernictvi'), name='ceniky-edit-kadernictvi'),
```

and I want to get value of "typ" in my view, how I can do that ? Thank you guys.

Answer (score 1):

for eg : if its post function 
 def post(self, request, **kwargs):
       typ=kwargs['typ']

Comment: @Honza Vacek This is assuming typ is in your url as a url parameter. your question doesn't have this but We're assuming that's what you meant. Please clarify if this is not so.